# How to use margin-bottom to create length of the web page

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div style="width:300px;height:3000px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;margin-bottom:1000px;background-color:#00f;">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The idea is to have a 3000 px high block and then a 1000 px space. But the space is ignored when I test the code in Safari. Works fine in Chrome though. Not sure in IE. What should I do?

Comment: Space is not ignored in [my test](http://jsfiddle.net/td8cjq00/).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it http://jsfiddle.net/vjgezbxb/1/

Comment: I think he want 1000px white space under the blue box, `margin-bottom:1000px`

Comment: @Gerret Check the fiddle it gives white space under the box

Comment: @Gerret Check both fiddles above. The space is under the blue box.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen it is not working for me I just see the blue box and no space... So it could be the browser? I am using firefox

Comment: both fiddles don't have spaces below on chromium-browser

Comment: I just checked the code with other browsers. You guys are right. Works in Chrome. But it doesn't work in Safari. I use OS X 10.10 beta. Changed the question. Sorry!

Comment: @Gerret Seems indeed to be browser-dependent. Post was updated as well. Using Chromium here.

Comment: I'm only seeing a 3000px page with chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it works, like Robby and Richa have already commented.

But if you want to visally see the "space" try this code (within the body tag of course)

```
<div style=" width:300px; height:3000px; position:absolute; 
 top:0px; left:0; margin-bottom:1000px; background-color:#00f; ">
</div>
<div style=" width:300px; height:3000px; position:absolute; 
 top:4000px; left:0; margin-bottom:1000px; background-color:#00f; ">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted space at the bottom of the div. Try this code below:

```
<div style="width:300px; height:3000px; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0; background-color:#00f; ">
</div>
<div style="width:300px; height:1000px; position:absolute; top:3000px; left:0; background-color:#fff; ">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

body {
    height:4000px;
}

I don't know why but
Per [Set position absolute and margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350775/set-position-absolute-and-margin)

> margin-bottom will only do anything to an absolutely-positioned
>   element if the element has no top property.