# Absolutely positioned element and margin-bottom

Tags: html, css, css-position, margin, absolute

I want to apply margin bottom on an absolutely positioned element but it doesn't work.

Here's my code
Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="absolute"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

I want to create a space between the first and the second item. I thought of using a margin-top on the second item, but the height of the first item changes cos of the content inside it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set position absolute and margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350775/set-position-absolute-and-margin)

Comment: Have you tried adding a `padding-bottom` to your container?

Comment: You can't use margin on absolute position, use `bottom:20px;`

Comment: CSS should be lowercase and you're missing `;` at the end of every line.

Comment: It is worth putting your code through a validator - it's full of errors as @j08691 has pointed out. Also use your browser's devtools to find out exactly what CSS is being applied. In this case though you need to understand that an absolute positioned element is taken out of the normal flow and doesn't affect other elements' positioning so a margin on it will make no difference to the following div.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it can be done through `padding-bottom`. Then for the `item2` you can add `margin-top` that will probably help you resolve your issue.

Also, this might be helpful to you [Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-can-i-center-an-absolutely-positioned-element-in-a-div?rq=2)

Comment: How will adding padding to an absolutely positioned element affect the positioning of any other element?

Comment: It will affect the size of the content in the element not directly affect the positioning of the element.

Comment: My point was that doesn't affect the positioning of *any other* element, because the element itself is absolutely positioned.